# Moving code to a function causing script to stop

Tags: php

I'd like to use a block of code to initialize an emailer but every time I move the code to a function the script stops executing before it sends the email. When I load the web page using this function it works fine and sends the appropriate emails:

```
function SendAdminIntimationEmail(&$formvars)
{
    if(empty($this->admin_email))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mailer->isSMTP();

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mailer->Host = "test.com";

    //Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
    $mailer->Port = 25;

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = false;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication
    $mailer->Username = "test@test.com";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mailer->Password = "pword";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mailer->setFrom('test@test.com', 'test');

    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mailer->addReplyTo('test@test.com', 'First Last');

    $mailer->AddAddress($this->admin_email);

    $mailer->Subject = "New registration: ".$formvars['name'];

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();         

    $mailer->Body ="A new user registered at ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
    "Name: ".$formvars['name']."\r\n".
    "Email address: ".$formvars['email']."\r\n".
    "UserName: ".$formvars['username'];

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when I move a block of the code to a separate function and try to pass that function the $mailer object the webpage loads a blank page and doesn't send an email. The non-working code:

```
function SendAdminIntimationEmail(&$formvars)
{
    if(empty($this->admin_email))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    InitSMTPMailer($mailer);

    $mailer->AddAddress($this->admin_email);

    $mailer->Subject = "New registration: ".$formvars['name'];

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();         

    $mailer->Body ="A new user registered at ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
    "Name: ".$formvars['name']."\r\n".
    "Email address: ".$formvars['email']."\r\n".
    "UserName: ".$formvars['username'];

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function InitSMTPMailer($mailer)
{
    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mailer->isSMTP();

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mailer->Host = "test.com";

    //Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
    $mailer->Port = 25;

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = false;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication
    $mailer->Username = "test@test.com";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mailer->Password = "pword";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mailer->setFrom('test@test.com', 'test');

    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mailer->addReplyTo('test@test.com', 'test');

    return $mailer;
}
```

If it's useful, this function is always called by this function:

```
function RegisterUser()
{
    if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
       return false;
    }

    $formvars = array();

    if(!$this->ValidateRegistrationSubmission())
    {
        return false;
    }

    $this->CollectRegistrationSubmission($formvars);

    if(!$this->SaveToDatabase($formvars))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!$this->SendUserConfirmationEmail($formvars))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $this->SendAdminIntimationEmail($formvars);

    return true;
}
```

After adding the function that's making the script not work correctly, it appears that RegisterUser() fails at the  $this->SendAdminIntimationEmail($formvars); line, because the SendUserConfirmationEmail($formvars) function still sends an email.

I'm new to PHP so sorry if this is simple, but am I doing something wrong with passing an object by references or value which is braking something?

Comment: blank page = php crashed and you have all debug options disabled. turn them on, and try again. they should never be OFF on a devel/debug system in the first place. it's the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingersi in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you"

Comment: Are these functions part of a class? `$this` is for use within a class.

Comment: `InitSMTPMailer` returns mailer, but you're not assigning it, and you're not passing it by reference.

Comment: @aynber dons't metter. It's object. It will always passed by referrence

Comment: "SendAdminIntimationEmail" и "InitSMTPMailer" are in the same class?

Comment: @Arnial yes they are part of the same class.

Comment: @aynber I've tried passing it by reference (using &) and assigning a the return value but neither have been successful. Does a function have to have a return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that you call `InitSMTPMailer` wrong way.

`SendAdminIntimationEmail` and `InitSMTPMailer` are class methods, but you calling `InitSMTPMailer` as global function (or just forget `$this->`).

Try this:

```
function SendAdminIntimationEmail(&$formvars)
{
    if(empty($this->admin_email))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();

    $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $this->InitSMTPMailer($mailer);

    $mailer->AddAddress($this->admin_email);

    $mailer->Subject = "New registration: ".$formvars['name'];

    $mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();         

    $mailer->Body ="A new user registered at ".$this->sitename."\r\n".
    "Name: ".$formvars['name']."\r\n".
    "Email address: ".$formvars['email']."\r\n".
    "UserName: ".$formvars['username'];

    if(!$mailer->Send())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I don't have enough reputation to up vote but the reasoning to your answer was exactly what I was looking for. I've been more or less confused on the use of $this-> and couldn't seem to find a clear answer anywhere. Thanks again!